# Send an email notification on for all Task due on that day

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I want to send an email notification on the day the task is due.
I created a time triggered flow checking to execute on "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

does that mean it will only execute when record is edited? What if its not? What if someone creates a task and leaves it.

Also if I have 5 tasks due today, so will it send 5 emails? how can i have it send 1 email listing all the tasks due that day.
[image: See attached image]
I followed instructions on salesforce to set reminder set. This field is set at times and not all times

Answer (score 0):

> does that mean it will only execute when record is edited? What if its not? What if someone creates a task and leaves it.

The time-dependent action will be enqueued for future execution if the record meets the Workflow Rule entry criteria when it is created or if it is edited to meet those criteria.

If the record is edited to no longer meet the entry criteria, the enqueued time-dependent action won't be executed.

---

> how can i have it send 1 email listing all the tasks due that day.

You can't do this with a Workflow Rule.

You can build this functionality in Apex or Flow, or you can create a Report on Tasks due today and have your users create Report Subscriptions to receive an email digest.

In my opinion, automated emails are generally an antipattern: I suggest using the out-of-the-box Activity components on a home page instead, or using Report Subscriptions, or positioning a Report or Dashboard on the home page.